# Thread stops working after 5 minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I implemented async file processing with the technique described in "[Running Rails jobs in background threads](https://www.agileplannerapp.com/blog/building-agile-planner/rails-background-jobs-in-threads)":

```
def upload_images
    begin
      uploaded_io = params[:filetoupload]
      File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
        file.write(uploaded_io.read)
        file.flush
        job = Job.create(:status => 0, :file_name => uploaded_io.original_filename)
        processing_job(job)
      end
    rescue => e
      upload_log.error(e.to_s)
    end
    redirect_to '/admin/jobs'
  end

  def processing_job(job)
    background do
      # do processing
    end
  end

  def background(&block)
    Thread.new do
      yield
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
    end
  end
```

But after about 5 minutes of working, the thread stops processing data: logging stops, CPU load is almost zero. The free memory is also not the issue.

Why does this happen and how it could be solved?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3p551, Rails 4.1.9, Phusion Passenger 4.0.59.

Comment: Which server do you use (unicorn, thin, puma)?

Comment: @slowjack2k: Phusion Passenger 4.0.59

Comment: Phusion is a threated server wihtout knowing what your background job does I would say physions threathandling interacts with your threat. Maybe you should go the Rails Way and create a messaging based background job.